# Extracting date part of datetime really necessary?

Tags: mysql

Consider following two queries (one uses `DATE()` function to extract date from datetime field and other one does not).

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM  creatives 
WHERE DATE(creative_last_seen) >= SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1 ) 
AND DATE(creative_last_seen) < curdate();
```

Total response time: **1 min 19 sec**

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM  creatives 
WHERE creative_last_seen >= SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1 ) 
AND creative_last_seen < curdate();
```

Total response time: **8.9 sec**

Both queries are producing identical results as far as I can tell. The first query because of date extraction takes huge amount of time while the other one is significantly faster.

I initially thought I needed to use `DATE()` function to make the query work. But it seems to be working just fine without the `DATE()` function. Am I missing anything by using the latter query?

Answer (score 0):

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part 
>   The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts

As `creative_last_seen` `datetime` data type it includes time portion which will be taken into consideration during the comparison.

If you are only interested in `date` comparison not `time` you can use the first query

If you want the `time` part should be considered during the comparison then go with the second query

**DEMO**

```
select NOW() > CURDATE();
# output : 1

select date(NOW()) > CURDATE();
# output : 0
```